# Which gives better performance: len(a[:-1]) or len(a)-1

Tags: python, range, slice

In Python which is better in terms of performance:

1)

```
for i in range(len(a[:-1])):
    foo()
```

or

2)

```
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    foo()
```

**UPDATE:**

Some context on why I'm looping over indices (non-idiomatic?):

```
for c in reversed(range(len(self._N)-1)):
    D[c] =  np.dot(self._W[c], D[c-1])*A[c]*(1-A[c])
```

Comment: `a[:-1]` creates a new string/list (which is unnecessary) while `len(a)` simply returns the length. Now, which one do you think is better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range(0, len(a) - 1)` should be more performant of the 2 options.  The other makes an unnecessary copy of the sequence (sans 1 element).  For looping like this, you might even get a performance boost by using `xrange` on python2.x as that avoids materializing a list from the `range` call.

Of course, you *usually* don't need to loop over indices in python -- There's usually a better way.

Comment: @mgilson Good point, I added some context on why I'm looping over indices.

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for the xrange tip!

Answer (score 4):

The second one is better, two reasons:

1. The first one created a new list `a[:-1]`, which **takes up unnecessary time & memory**, the second one didn't create a new list.
2. The second one is more intuitive and clear.

> [:] returns a `shallow copy` of a list. it means that every slice notation returns a list which have new address in memory, but its elements would have same addresses that elements of source list have.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `a[:-1]` creates a new list for which you take the length and discard the list. This is *O*(n) time and space complexity, compared to *O*(1) time and space complexity for the second example.

Comment: to be honest the time complexity almost certainly does not make a noticeable difference ... even for huge lists ..

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm hoping that since the OP is asking the question, they are actually operating on big enough lists that this would make a difference.

Comment: ok you guys are totally right ... thats what I get for just skimming the question (I didnt even realize it was asking about performance until a comment in my answer :P) (+1)

Comment: for the case of `a = [None] * 10000` I'm seeing a `timeit` difference of ~1000 fold (50 µs vs. 80 ns)

Answer (score 1):

neither is the right way

```
for i,item in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    ...
```

is how you should probably do it ...

in general in python you should never do

```
 for i in range(len(a_list)):  ...
```

here are the timing differences

```
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in range(len(a)-1):x=i","a=range(1000000)",number=100)
3.30806345671283
>>> timeit.timeit("for i in enumerate(a[:-1]):x=i","a=range(1000000)",number=100
5.3319918613661201
```

as you can see it takes an extra 2 seconds to do 100 times on a large list of integers ... but its still a better idea imho

Comment: Since this question is about performance, isn't there a performance hit to making the list copy in the `enumerate`?

Comment: easy to test ... hold on ... I suspect it will be very negligible

Comment: It is costly for sufficiently large values of len(a).

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Not that easy to test.  You don't know anything about the size/type of OP's input... although in most cases it really shouldn't matter...

Comment: I've done enough high performance programming in my time to know that elegant and efficient are oftentimes mutually exclusive.